# Image does not load on Flutter Draw Header

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-drawer

I'm new to flutter-dart and I've been trying to load a image to my draw header, so far unsuccessfully. Can anyone shed some light on it? Please find my code below.

```
class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/title_fb_600.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
            child: Text("Some Text"),
            //ListTile(
            // leading: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
            // title: Text(
            // "TRIPLE A",
            // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            //  ),
          ),
          ItemDrawer("Carteira Recomendada", Icons.star, 16),
          ItemDrawer("Carteira R\$10", Icons.ten_k, 16),
          ItemDrawer("Minha Carteira", Icons.favorite, 16),
          ItemDrawer("Notícias", Icons.new_releases, 16),
          ItemDrawer("Minha Conta", Icons.account_circle, 16),
          ItemDrawer("Configurações", Icons.settings, 16),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml....

```
> flutter:
> 
uses-material-design: true
> 
assets:
>     - assets/images/title3a_fb_600.png
```

And folder structure...

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yg5D.png)

Comment: Would you mind to show your directory tree? Where are `lib` and `assets`?

Comment: The path here you have added is  ```image: AssetImage('assets/images/title_fb_600.png')```  where your image name is not matched as declared in pubspec.yaml is ```title3a_fb_600.png```

Comment: Spot on Ronak, that also solved the issue. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pubspec file looks good. I'm assuming you only want to include this single image as an asset.

Try using this package, and replacing the **DrawerHeader** class with a **ProgressiveImage** component here.
https://pub.dev/packages/progressive_image

This package helps you to cache the image, to prevent having to reload it again, and it also adds a blur animation while it loads this asset.

If you need to layer the drawer header (and add other information, such as an avatar icon, or email information), you can add this component into a **Stack** collection, then make sure that the **ProgressiveImage** is the first in the **Stack**

If you also need to set a custom height to the drawer header, then make sure to wrap this **Stack** with a **Container** and manually set the height of this element

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you @Dan Gerchovich.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as the answer for this post, so you don't get more suggestions from people